# Render to GDI+ only in grayscale

Tags: gdi+

I'm building an app with a Print Preview function. If the printer does not support color, I want to render everything in grayscale. I depend on 3P rendering libraries where I can't change the color they render with.

Without resorting to rendering to an offscreen bitmap, and then converting it to grayscale, etc... is there any way to just tell GDI+ to render grayscale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such possibility to tell the Graphics object to draw in grayscale (afaik).

You have three possibilities:

1) Render to an offscreen image (what you don't want)

2) Make a screenshot of your current render result and convert it to grayscale and draw it over your current render result (not a nice solution in my eyes)

3) Tweak your current rendering code and convert all used colors to grayscale

To convert a color to grayscale you can use this code:

```
public Color ToGrayScaleColor(Color originalColor)
{
    int grayScale = (int)((originalColor.R * .3) + (originalColor.G * .59) + (originalColor.B * .11));
    return Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
}
```

Code found and adjusted from http://csharp-me.blogspot.com/2014/01/convert-color-to-gray-scale-in-c-c-sharp.html

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time. If what I wanted to do wasn't possible (as i suspected) I would need to go down path #3, so you've saved me having to think about that with your answer. Thanks.